# Troubleshooting PHP Access Violations

Tags: windows, iis, php, windows-xp, web-server

My company is running IIS on XP.  Every other day we get a PHP Access Violation and the only way I know to fix it is to restart IIS.  I've googled the actual Access violation code and i can't find anything. There's nothing in the php error logs or the system error logs.

Anyone have any advice on how to go about fixing this?

edit: It seems to happen on pages that use the google maps api.

Comment: I suggest you ask on StackOverflow as well .. this is very likely a problem with PHP rather than the server.  If you get something there please post it!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the PHP error logs, nothing in the system error logs... where do you "get" the PHP access violation?  Any information you get at that time would be a useful addition to your post as well.

"Access violation" normally means a memory pointer bug; whatever's going wrong is likely to be buried in some module you're using.  In your situation, I'd probably try upgrading PHP and any libraries it depends on to the latest version, particularly focusing on anything relevant to your Google Maps integration, in hopes that it's a bug that's been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The "violation code" will literally be a random memory address, and will (should) change with every one you see, so google won't be able to help.

You could install xdebug and trace it while google-api'ing.

When next the error appears, hopefully your output will instead be a huge stack-trace detailing exactly which module is faulting and where.

http://xdebug.org/